# Do Data Tier Application Projects replace Database Projects from Visual Studio Database Edition?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-data-tools

I'm only slightly familiar with the features of Data Tier Applications and what Database Projects did in the Database Edition of visual studio.

Are these two different overlapping solutions for database version control?  Or does Data Tier Application functionality replace outright the need to use visual studio database edition and database projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the difference between Database Projects and Data Tier Projects is at the point of deployment. If you want to create a dacpac, you'd use the Data Tier Project. If you want to createa .dbschema and sql migration file, you'd use the conventional Database Project.

As far as I'm aware, Data Tier Applications are expected to be important in future for SQL Azure deployment.

Unless you're specifically looking at SQL Azure, I'd use Database Projects for now. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve. It could be that [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) (by Red Gate, the company I work for) is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for putting the two microsoft products in perspective. I will definitely take a close look at your company's solution too. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: We're hoping to 'support' the database project in SQL Source Control sometime later next year, but this business decision will rely on increased uptake of database projects.

Comment: I wonder what your opinion is on the current state of things. It seems VS 2013+ "Database Projects" spit out dacpac files when you build them. Are Data-Tier applications still around? Have these two concepts been merged?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft merged Database Projects and Data-Tier Applications in to the new SSDT database project. The dacpac is the deployment artifact that is compared with the target to generate a script. Many believe that a safer deployment mechanism is to use migration scripts, for example like ready-roll does.

Answer (score 7):

DAC provides an application model which can be used as an interface between developers and DBAs.  The developer edits the model, the DBA manages/deploys from the model.  For example, once the model is built or extracted, it can be deployed to multiple servers.

Imagine the .dacpac as an .exe.  The developer builds an .exe and hands it off to someone.  At this point, it would be nice if the developer doesn't have to worry about where that .exe runs because the .exe is internally consistent - it either runs or it doesn't.  Why should the developer need to worry about targetting 2008, 2005, or Azure specifically?  Just develop the app model and let DAC take care of the rest...

Having this deployment artifact also provides some new capabilities.  Examples include versioned deployments, the ability to determine if someone has changed the database since the last deployment or upgrade, the ability to create the same database in different target servers.

Do you like having to manage a library of upgrade scripts for your various databases?  Wouldn't it be nice if the entire state of your database could be built or captured (extracted) at any point in time?

The database application project mashup in VS 2010 will be resolved in an upcoming release of database-centric developer tools.  Investing in dbschema or DAC wont affect forward compatibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for this additional answer.  You really helped clarify DAC.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Visual Studio database projects are targeted at developers.

Data Tier Applications are targeted at DBAs. See [this blog](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/sql-server-2008-r2-the-dac-pack/) for details.

Comment: But data tier applications are supposed to be built by "database developers" not the DBAs.  and they're supposed to be built in visual studio, not SSMS

Comment: I think the idea is that the dacpacs are built by developers but handed over to the DBA for easy deployment using a wizard in SSMS. The output of database projects is a sql file that is also passed to the DBA and must be run against the target server.